# React Native black screen without Debugger on

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I already have an iOs app made with React Native and I'm starting to port it to Android.

The app works fine on iOS and on Android with Chrome Debugging turned on. Without the debugging, the app opens with a blank screen with no content in it.

This is the log that I'm getting when I try `react-native log-android`

```
05-22 23:09:58.703  7831  7921 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
05-22 23:09:58.704  7831  7921 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
05-22 23:09:58.718  7831  7921 D ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
05-22 23:09:58.718  7831  7921 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
05-22 23:09:58.718  7831  7923 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
05-22 23:09:58.718  7831  7923 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
05-22 23:09:58.719  7831  7923 D ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
05-22 23:09:59.177  7831  7831 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.destroy() start
05-22 23:09:59.243  7831  7831 D ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.destroy() start
```

On the device (Android), Im' getting the following error and the screen is blank:
[image]

As said, when I activate Chrome debugging, the app works fine and renders successfully.

I'm using:

```
"react": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
"react-native": "0.54.4"
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Maybe some asynchronism problem ?

Comment: @BrunoMazzardo Anyway I can test this?

Comment: No idea, the problem is too vague, there are infinite reasons this could be happening, without looking at the code, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Please provide the sample code/screenshots.

Comment: @akshaygore what part of the code should I post?? I really have no clue Where the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

this is because you use the debug bundle, you should output release bundle and use it.

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

this is ios command

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios/a
```